# PyroCMS Execute code after stream has saved

Tags: php, codeigniter, pyrocms

So I've got a PyroCMS project that I'm working on that is a backend for a mobile app. What I'm trying to do is send push notifications when a certain stream gets a new entry.

From what I've read [here](https://forum.pyrocms.com/discussion/24913/intercept-stream-form-on-save), it looks like there is no way to tell when the form data is actually saved with cp->entry_form()

Anyone have any insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events to the rescue!

Check out [the docs on events](http://docs.pyrocms.com/2.2/manual/developers/tools/events).

Basically you'll have to create an `events.php` in your module (and maybe even create a small module with no functionality besides this) and register for the `streams_post_insert_entry` and `streams_post_update_entry` events.

Example events.php:

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Events_Yourmodule
{
    protected $ci;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->ci =& get_instance();

        Events::register('streams_post_insert_entry', array($this, 'delete_cache'));
        Events::register('streams_post_update_entry', array($this, 'delete_cache'));     
    }

    public function delete_cache( $event )
    {
        // check if the event is for the stream we're interested in
        if($event['stream']->stream_slug != 'the-stream-im-interested-in')
          return;

        // now, do stuff... like delete cache
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This works like a charm. I've had some good experience with  code igniter, but didn't know how tightly integrated it was within pryo.